# Filter array of objects using multipule filters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array of objects using a 'filters' object. The 'filters' object below should filter the array for object with type: 'toys' OR 'electronics', language: 'English' OR 'Spanish'. I'm trying to create a function that would return the last object (`name: 'StoreF'`) based on the provided filter as an example.

```
var filters = {
                country: ["France"],
                type: ["toys", "electronics"],
                language: ["English", "Spanish"]

            }
        var stores = [{
                name: "StoreA",
                country: "United States",
                type: ["toys", "groceries"],
                language: ["English", "Spanish"]
            },
            {
                name: "StoreB",
                country: "Spain",
                type: ["toys"],
                language: ["English", "Spanish"]
            },
            {
                name: "StoreC",
                country: "France",
                type: ["autoparts"],
                language: ["French"]
            },
            {
                name: "StoreD",
                country: "Thailand",
                type: ["toys"],
                language: ["Thai"]
            },
            {
                name: "StoreE",
                country: "India",
                type: ["toys"],
                language: ["English"]
            },
            {
                name: "StoreF",
                country: "France",
                type: ["toys"],
                language: ["English", "French"]
            },
        ]
```

Using this function works fine until I introduce 2 filters for the same category (i.e `language: ["English", "Spanish"]`).

```
function nestedFilter(targetArray, filters) {
            var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
            return targetArray.filter(function(eachObj) {
                return filterKeys.every(function(eachKey) {
                    if (!filters[eachKey].length) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(eachObj[eachKey])) {
                        return eachObj[eachKey].includes(filters[eachKey]);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

nestedFilter(stores, filters);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OR you need `some` not `every`.

```js
const res = stores.filter(store =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([key , value]) => value.some(e => 
        store[key].includes(e)
    )));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const filters = {
    country: ["France"],
    type: ["toys", "electronics"],
    language: ["English", "Spanish"]
};

const stores = [
    {
        name: "StoreA",
        country: "United States",
        type: ["toys", "groceries"],
        language: ["English", "Spanish"]
    },
    {
        name: "StoreB",
        country: "Spain",
        type: ["toys"],
        language: ["Engilsh", "Spanish"]
    },
    {
        name: "StoreC",
        country: "France",
        type: ["autoparts"],
        language: ["French"]
    },
    {
        name: "StoreD",
        country: "Thailand",
        type: ["toys"],
        language: ["Thai"]
    },
    {
        name: "StoreE",
        country: "India",
        type: ["toys"],
        language: ["Engilsh"]
    },
    {
        name: "StoreF",
        country: "France",
        type: ["toys"],
        language: ["English", "French"]
    },
];
</script>
```

Also note the multiple typos in your stores, Engilsh won't return true for English